# Are there any good tricks for finding the inverse of a matrix via Gauss-Jordan elimination when that matrix has lots of zeroes?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, gaussian-elimination

Suppose we're given a square matrix $A$, say $4 \times 4$. If we're asked to find it's determinant by hand, a nice trick is to find a row or column with lots of zeroes (examiners love giving these kinds of matrices, who really knows why...) along which to perform a cofactor expansion.

Suppose that instead of being asked to find the determinant, we're asked to find the inverse by Gauss-Jordan elimination. In this case, it's less clear to me how to exploit the rows and columns with many zeroes to simplify the problem.

> **Question.** Are there any good tricks for finding the inverse of matrix with many zeroes via Gauss-Jordan elimination?

For example, to invert something like this:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
    2 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
    -1 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
    3 & 0 & 3 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$

are there any nice tricks for exploiting that column of mostly $0$'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interchanging the first two columns of $A$ corresponds to interchanging the first two rows of $A^{-1}$, and interchanging the first two rows of $A$ 
corresponds to interchanging the first two columns of $A^{-1}$.  After doing those interchanges, you have a matrix where the first column of Gauss-Jordan has been (almost) done already.